# Bad encoding when inserting to table from script and source file

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, character-encoding

I have a MySQL source (inserts) that I apply on after boot in Debían.

The file is in `UTF8`, and in the bash script I start the MySQL service and make an EOF (heredoc) with command `source path/to/file.sql` to a `UTF8 table` (show create table says)

But when I connect to the server to check the data, it is displaying tilde characters as weird chars. So I put `set names "latin1"` and it showed correctly.

However, if I skip the script and connect manually, then source the sql, it inserts the characters OK.

So the problem is in the script connection, but how could it differ from my insert if I am executing the same commands in the script but manually.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be that the user inserting after boot wasn't interactive, it didn't have `LANG` variable set, so was falling back to default `latin1`.

One solution is to set `SET NAMES 'utf8'` on top of all sql files.

The other is to set the `LANG` variable in the system.

This is from the manual:

> The MySQL client programs mysql, mysqladmin, mysqlcheck, mysqlimport,
>   and mysqlshow determine the default character set to use as follows:
>
> In the absence of other information, the programs use the compiled-in default character set, usually latin1.
>
> The programs can autodetect which character set to use based on the operating system setting, such as the value of the LANG or LC_ALL
>   locale environment variable on Unix systems or the code page setting
>   on Windows systems. For systems on which the locale is available from
>   the OS, the client uses it to set the default character set rather
>   than using the compiled-in default. For example, setting LANG to
>   ru_RU.KOI8-R causes the koi8r character set to be used. Thus, users
>   can configure the locale in their environment for use by MySQL
>   clients.
>
> The OS character set is mapped to the closest MySQL character set if there is no exact match. If the client does not support the
>   matching character set, it uses the compiled-in default. For example,
>   ucs2 is not supported as a connection character set.